# $H_1 ,H_2 \unlhd \, G$ with $H_1 \cap H_2 = \{1_G\} $. Prove every two elements in $H_1, H_2$ commute

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, proof-explanation, normal-subgroups

This is the proof, which I mostly understand except for one bit:

You have $h_1 \in H_1$ and $h_2 \in H_2$.

We also have $h_1^{-1}(h_2^{-1}h_1h_2) \in H_1$, because $h_2^{-1}h_1h_2 \in h_2^{-1}H_1h_2 = H_1$. Similarly, we have $(h_1^{-1}h_2^{-1}h_1)h_2 \in H_2$. Therefore

$$
h_1^{-1}h_2^{-1}h_1h_2 \in H_1 \cap H_2 = \{1_G\}
$$

and so $h_1^{-1}h_2^{-1}h_1h_2 = \{1_G\}$. Let's first multiply everything on the left by $h_1$

$$h_1^{-1}h_2^{-1}h_1h_2 = \{1_G\}$$
$$ h_1 h_1^{-1}h_2^{-1}h_1h_2 = h_1 \{1_G\}$$
$$ h_2^{-1}h_1h_2 = h_1 \{1_G\}$$

Multiply both sides on the left by $h_2$ giving us

$$
h_1h_2 = h_2 h_1 $$

The bit I don't get is right at the beginning. Why is this correct: "We also have $h_1^{-1}(h_2^{-1}h_1h_2) \in H_1$, because $h_2^{-1}h_1h_2 \in h_2^{-1}H_1h_2 = H_1$."

Comment: If you look at the part in parentheses, the argument shows that is an element in $H_1$, which is due directly to the fact that $H_1$ is a normal subgroup. It's clear $h_1^{-1}$ is an element, and since $H_1$ is a subgroup, it's closed under its operations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$H_1$ is normal in $G$, so for any $g\in G$ you have $g^{-1}H_1g \subseteq H_1$. So in particular with $g = h_2$ and $h_1\in H_1$:
$$
h_2^{-1}h_1h_2 \in H_1.
$$ 
Then multiplying by $h_1^{-1}\in H_1$ doesn't move us outside $H_1$, so
$$
h_1^{-1}(h_2^{-1}h_1h_2) \in H_1.
$$
About the next part (ref comment) you have the same. There you have $H_2$ a normal subgroup of $G$. So that means with $h_1 \in H \leq G$ and $h_2 \in H_2 \Rightarrow h_2^{-1} \in H_2$ you have $$h_1^{-1}h_2^{-1}h_1 \in H_2.$$ And so $$(h_1^{-1}h_2^{-1}h_1)h_2 \in H_2.$$

Comment: Does the $h_2^{-1}h_1h_2 \in H_1$ come from the defintion of a normal subgroup?

Comment: @Kaish: Yes exactly. $H$ is normal in $G$ means exactly that $g^{-1}hg \in H$ for all $h\in H$ and $g\in G$. Note that $h_2$ is here just considered as an element of $G$ (because $H_2 \leq G$). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_subgroup

Comment: So in the next line, with the similary bit, would it be:

$h_1^{-1}h_2^{-1}h_1 \in h_1^{-1} H_2 h_1 = H_2$?

Comment: @Kaish: I edited.

Answer (score 0):

This is another proof I made with concepts from my group theory class. For any subgroups $H,K$ we define in $H\times K$ the equivalence relation $(h_1,k_1)\equiv (h_2,k_2)$ if $h_1 k_1 = h_2 k_2$ and then the bijection

\begin{align}
\Phi: H&\cap K \rightarrow [(h,k)]\\
&x \longrightarrow (hx,x^{-1}k)
\end{align}

where $[(h,k)]$ is an equivalence class. From all of this, we get $||H\cap K||=|| [(h,k)]||$.

Once we have this, if $H,K \unlhd G$ and $H\cap K=\{1_G\}$. By contradiction, suppose that $\exists h_1 \in H$ such that $h_1k_1\neq k_1 h_1$. So, there exists $h_2 \in H$ such that $h_1\neq h_2$ and $h_1 k_1= k_1 h_2$ because $H$ is normal. Moreover, $K$ is also normal so $\exists k_2 \in K$ that $k_1 h_2 = h_2 k_2$. We can see that $(h_1,k_1)\equiv (h_2,k_2)$. Therefore, $|[(h_1,k_1)]| = |H\cap K| \geq 2$ which is a contradiction. So, $h_1k_1=k_1h_1$.