# If the intersection of two normal subgroups is trivial, then their elements commute

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

How to show that if $N \ \& \ M$ are 2 normal subgroups of group $G$ and $N\cap M=\{e\}$ (identity element), then for any $n\in N \ \&\ m\in M $, $nm=mn$?

Comment: Please, try to make the titles of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253131/h-1-h-2-unlhd-g-with-h-1-cap-h-2-1-g-prove-every-two-elements (Although probably not a duplicate, since the other question asks about explanation of one specific step in the proof provided by the OP.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If we can show that $m^{-1}nmn^{-1}=e$, then multiplying by $m$ and $n$ from the respective sides you'll get the desired result. Now, regarding the element $m^{-1}nmn^{-1}$: use the normality of $M$ and $N$ to show that it lies in both subgroups.