# Name for condition $A\cap B=\{e\}$ when $A$ and $B$ are algebraic structures

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, terminology

I find in many places of algebra notions like: let $A,B\subset X$ substructures of $X$ (namely subgroups, vector subspaces, etc.) with the property that $A\cap B=\{e\}$, where $e$ is a very special element of the algebraic structure of $X$, namely a neutral element of some operation defined in $X$.

I would like to know if there is a way to name such condition on substructures instead of saying that $A \oplus B$ or something like that. If the question is too broad just take the case that $X$ is a group and $e$ is the neutral element respect to the group operation.

Comment: For groups most people say "trivial intersection" (I randomly looked here and found [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784612/if-the-intersection-of-two-normal-subgroups-is-trivial-then-their-elements-comm) for example, and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66796/when-do-sylow-subgroups-have-trivial-intersection)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is long enough to be an answer, but from what I've read, saying "$A$ and $B$ trivially intersect" often suffices.

Comment: Short answers are the best answers. I think I've also seen it siad that way so you're probably right