# Does this alternative argument prove that if $H,K\triangleleft G$ and $H\cap K=\{e\}$, then $hk=kh$ for all $h\in H$, $k\in K$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

From Printers book.Ex. H2 chapter 14

Theres a hint ($hk=kh \iff hkh^{-1}k^{-1}=e$), and using the fact H,K are normal. I did it using the hint and it was ok.

My question is why cant I just say that by definition of H or K being normal $aH=Ha$, for any $a\in g$. So since $k\in G,  kH=Hk$ i.e. $kh=hk , \forall h \in H$

Or do I have a flawed understanding of definition of normal subgroup?

Comment: The fact that $kH=Hk$ does not mean that $k$ commutes with every element of $H$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$H_1 ,H_2 \unlhd \, G$ with $H_1 \cap H_2 = \{1_G\} $. Prove every two elements in $H_1, H_2$ commute](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253131/h-1-h-2-unlhd-g-with-h-1-cap-h-2-1-g-prove-every-two-elements)

Comment: To specify what@lulu said, $kH=Hk$ just imply that there exist $h_1,h_2\in H$ such that $kh_1=h_2k$, but doesn't necessarily holds that $h_1=h_2$.

Comment: $aH = Ha$ means the sets $aH$ and $Ha$ are same not $ah = ha$ for every $h \in H$. For example take $ G = \mathbb Z$, $H = 2\mathbb Z$ then the sets $1 + 2\mathbb Z$ and $3 + 2\mathbb Z$ are equal even though $1 \not = 3$. In fact it's the same set for any odd integer instead of $1$ and $3$.

Comment: Note that if your attempt held, then it would follow that $hk=kh$ for any $h\in H$ and $k\in K$ *regardless* of whether $H\cap K$ is trivial or not (your proposed argument never uses that $H\cap K=\{e\}$).  But this is certainly not the case: for example, in the quaternion group $Q_8$, $H=\langle i\rangle$ and $K=\langle j\rangle$ are both normal, but $ij\neq ji$. Use that example to see what the problem is: $jH=Hj$, but $jh$ need not equal $hj$ for all $h\in H$.

Comment: @Deif Yes this is precisely my misunderstanding, thankyou. Yes so in kH, $kh_1$ isnt necessarily equal to $h_1k$ in Hk, for some $h_1 \in H$.

Comment: @lulu. Yes Thats the way using the hint I think, which I did manage to do and understand. Thanks anyway

Comment: @lulu: That post solves the problem as per the hint. This post is asking what is incorrect about the argument in the third paragraph, which that post does not address.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin true.  I will retract my close vote accordingly.

Comment: @Shaun: That's not an accurate duplicate. The post is not asking for a proof, it's asking why the alternative argument does not work. The linked-to duplicate does not address that.

Comment: I'm sorry, @ArturoMagidin. I'll be more careful in future.

Comment: @TonyPizza, sorry to be pendantic but your example doesn't really make sense to me in the context of my question (Does k∈G,kH=Hk
 mean kh=hk,∀h∈H ?). I understood the other replies example with the quaternion group. Your example states that $aH=bH (= Hb) $  doesn't imply $ a=b$, without analysing the elements in the set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposed argument only uses the normality of $H$; it does not use the normality of $K$, nor does it use the fact that $H\cap K=\{e\}$. If your argument were correct, it would imply that every normal subgroup in every group is central... which is patently false.

The error is that the equality $kH=Hk$ holds at the level of *sets*. It says that
$$\{ kx\mid x\in H \} = \{yk\mid y\in H\}$$
(I'm using different variables to highlight the problem). That just says that for each $x\in H$ there exists a $y\in H$ such that $kx=yk$, and for each $y'\in H$ there exists an $x'\in H$ such that $y'k = kx'$. But it does not say that $x$ and $y$ are equal, or that $y'$ and $x'$ are equal. So you cannot conclude that $kx=xk$ for all $x\in H$, $k\in K$.

For an example where $H\triangleleft G$, $K\triangleleft G$, but not every element of $H$ commutes with every element of $K$, take $G=Q_8$, the quaternion group of order $8$, $H=\langle i\rangle$, $K=\langle j\rangle$. Note that $ij\neq ji$. And you can see that, for example,
$$\begin{align*}
jH &= \{j1, j(-1), ji, j(-i)\} = \{j, -j, -k, k\}\\
Hj &= \{1j, (-1)j, ij, (-i)j\} = \{j,-j, k, -k\}
\end{align*}$$
so that $jH=Hj$, but that's because $ji=(-i)j$ and $j(-i)=ij$, not because $jh=hj$ for all $h\in H$.